# how to set export LANG=en_US.utf-8 on screen terminal start (screenrc doesn't work)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, display, unicode

If I don't use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf-8
```

If I use screen

```
$ locale
LANG=C
```

how can I tell screen to use LANG=en_US.utf-8 so I can display unicode properly.

I tried `screen -U` but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using bash as your default shell, put the following line into your .bashrc file inside your home folder:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```